# How to load language file in Cor library from module language files in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using hmvc in codeigniter .. in application folder i have :

```
Core
Modules
```

I have some library in core folder and i want to use in it a language file from specific module >>
I have try that :

```
$this->lang->load("modules/" . $module . "/back/customers", "arabic");
```

But i get this error :

```
Unable to load the requested language file: language/arabic/modules/customers/back_lang.php
```

It goes to main language folder .. how can i solve it?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
$module = 'customers';
$module_path = APPPATH . 'modules/' . $module . '/';
$this->lang->load('back', 'arabic', false, true, $module_path);
```

And also you need to put your module language file in:

`application/modules/customers/language/arabic/back_lang.php`